# How to replace \r\n in textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea, smarty

PHP Code

```
<?php
$content = "check1\r\ncheck2\r\ncheck3\r\nend..."   
$order   = array("\r\n");
$replace = "\n";
$content= str_replace( $order, $replace, $content);
$smarty->assign('content', $content);
?>
```

View page (a smarty template)

```
<textarea>{$content}<textarea>
```

Output:

```
check1\r\ncheck2\r\ncheck3\r\nend...
```

I expect output like below

```
check1
check2
check3
end...
```

inside the textarea. I had replaced `\r\n` into `\n`, but even then I can't get my desired output. Whats wrong in my code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working for me, with an added semicolon on the first line: http://ideone.com/JngNo (I've also added `!!` so we can see it did something)

Comment: Ok, the the question is *completely* about Smarty, since the replace obviously works. Got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're having a similar problem to [this](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3555&sid=318cb4b1bd11d4bfb25d89bb1a99c61e).

If I'm reading correctly, try:

```
<textarea>{$content|stripcslashes}<textarea>
```

Comment: Obviously, I can't test it, but is seems close enough on http://ideone.com/jMZ4C . Next question - why am I answering questions in topics I know nothing about?

Comment: hah. exact same site I just found. Although you have a typo in your `stripslashes`

Comment: @ben - Thanks! Not a typo though, `stripslashes` didn't work for me: http://ideone.com/xv7k8 , it changed `'a\nb'` to `'anb'`. (again, assuming I understand correctly)

Comment: @Kobi you have an extra `c` in your strip-c-slashes

Comment: @Ben - I'm using http://www.php.net/stripcslashes ,  check out the two sample I did: http://ideone.com/jMZ4C , http://ideone.com/xv7k8

Comment: @Kobi, ah my bad. Thanks for the links. Learnt something new ;)

Comment: @Kobi. If i like to display it as html tags how to convert \r\n to <br /> and to display. i had used nl2br in smarty. but i cant print in html form. please help me how to display it

Comment: @Mohan Ram, probably best to post that as a separate question.

Comment: As an alternative to modifying the source data that is thrown at the Smarty template, I found that the template itself could be modified as follows (when used in conjunction with HTML_QuickForm): {if $form.frozen}{$form.address.html|stripcslashes|nl2br}{else}{$form.address.html|stripcslashes}{/if}

Answer (score 3):

I'm no *Smarty* guru, but you might want this in your template instead:

```
<textarea>{$content|stripslashes}<textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

This replaces all `\r\n` with `\n`.

```
$content = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $content);
```

I have used that successfully a couple of days ago, and they come out correctly in a text field.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the `\r\n`, but I had to add extra backslashes to the search argument (i.e., `\r\n` becomes `\\r\\n`) to make it work:

`$content = str_replace("\\r\\n","\r\n",$content);`